# Android java.lang.NoClassDefError when using external jar

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting the following message when referencing a JAR I have added to my Android project:

[image: error message]

The JAR is located in my libs/ folder

[image: libs/ folder contents]

[image]

and is directly referenced in the Build Path

[image]

The JAR is 'checked' in the "Order and Export" tab

[image]

From what information I can gather on adding JARs to Android projects, this procedure seems to be correct. Any clue as to what is causing this error?

Comment: you should check if this particular class is present in the particular package in the jar.

Comment: try moving your .jar file directly into lib folder rather than putting it in sub directory of libs.

Comment: Addict, it is. Edited the question with a screeny. Kedarnath - I tried that a few times, but ill give it another go (I changed some other settings since).

Comment: Tried again, but still, no dice